# Replace cart-id with order-id in db after validation, module prestashop 1.7.8.8

Tags: redirect, prestashop, payment-gateway, payment, prestashop-1.7

I'm working on a payment module in PrestaShop 1.7. I need to pass and store `orderid` in the `merchant_ref_number` parameter in request URL to payment page. Since it is not possible to capture the `orderid` before validation, so whatever i code it passes the `cartid` because its then only thing available before the validation.

I tried everything I could but order id doesn't passes in `merchant_ref_number` table in the DB. Is there any way where I could first pass the `cartid` during redirection to payment page and then update the `cartid` with `orderid` after validation? If that's possible, please help.

I tried using `hookActionValidateOrder` to update but its not working. no matter what i do it always passes the `cartid`. My code below:

```php
public function hookActionValidateOrder($params)
{
  // Retrieve the generated order ID
  $orderId = $params['order']->reference;

  // Retrieve the cart ID from the database
  $cartId = $this->getCartIdFromDatabase($orderId);

  // Update the merchant_Ref_number field with the order ID in the database
  $this->updateMerchantRefNumber($cartId, $orderId);

}

public function getCartIdFromDatabase($orderId)
{
  $query = new DbQuery();
  $query->select('id_cart');
  $query->from('orders');
  $query->where('id_order = ' . (int)$orderId);

  $cartId = Db::getInstance()->getValue($query);

  return $cartId;
}

public function updateMerchantRefNumber($cartId, $orderId)
{
  // Assuming the merchant_Ref_number field is in a table named 'cart'
  $sql = 'UPDATE `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'cart` SET `merchant_ref_number` = \'' . pSQL($orderId) . '\' WHERE `id_cart` = ' . (int)$cartId;
  Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
}
```

`paymentOptions` function code:

```php
public function hookPaymentOptions($params) {
   // Check if this module is enabled if (!$this->active) { return; } 
  $action = 'https://lateralpayments.com/hps/hps_Payment.aspx';
  $inputs = $this->latpayInput();

  // Set the payment option details
  $externalOption = new PaymentOption();
  $externalOption->setCallToActionText($this->l('Pay with Latpay'))
      ->setAction($action)
      ->setInputs($inputs)
      ->setAdditionalInformation($this->context->smarty->fetch('module:latpayredirect/views/templates/front/payment_infos.tpl'));
      
  return [$externalOption];
}

protected function latpayInput() {
  global $smarty, $cart;
  $Merchant_User_Id = Configuration::get('latpayredirect_Merchant_User_Id');
  $merchantpwd = Configuration::get('latpayredirect_merchantpwd');
  $Purchase_summary = Configuration::get('latpayredirect_Purchase_summary');
  $SecretKey = Configuration::get('latpayredirect_salt');
  $processurl = Configuration::get('latpayredirect_process_url');
  $order_id = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
  $merchant_ref_number = trim( (string) $order_id );
  //......some codes.....

  //Merchant Data
  $merchant_data = array();
  $merchant_data['Merchant_User_Id']      = $Merchant_User_Id;
  $merchant_data['merchantpwd']         = $merchantpwd;
  $merchant_data['Purchase_summary']         = $Purchase_summary;
  $merchant_data['currencydesc']           = $currencydesc;
  $merchant_data['merchant_ref_number']     = $merchant_ref_number;

  //.........some more codes......
}
```

I tried passing below , didnt work:

```php
  $order_id = (int) $this->context->cart->id;
  $merchant_ref_number = trim( (string) $order_id );
```

Update: If not for the situation stated above, is there another method I could modify the default order reference such that it matches the value of the merchant_ref_number(custom generated characters) parameter, perhaps by overriding a class? Has anyone attempted this before?